# Where is the ESX Swap file in ESX 4.1i installed on SD cards?

Tags: vmware-esxi, swap, sd-card

Where is the ESX swap file located?

I have installed ESXi 4.1 on a pair of mirrored SD coards, which came with the Dell server.  ESXi runs really quickly, but with no local disks apart from the SD cards, where is the ESX swap file located, as I am running the machine with 320GB RAM so I am assuming that I will be looking for a 320GB swap file somewhere and cannot find it!!

Regards,

Steven

Answer (score 1):

Click on your host -> config tab -> software advanced settings -> scratchConfig

The swap can end up on shared storage.

Hope that helps